# How to combine date and time to datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I just found the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JoinDateAndTime
(
    @d datetime,
    @t datetime
)
RETURNS Datetime
as
    BEGIN
        declare @res datetime
        set @res = convert (datetime, Convert(varchar(10), @d, 104) + ' ' + convert(varchar(8), @t, 108), 104)
        return @res
    END
go
```

After seeing the answers to [How to the get current date without the time part](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/how-to-the-get-current-date-without-the-time-part) I'm sure that involving conversions to varchar can't be the best solution.

BTW I searched SO for this question, but only found a solution for mySql.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The time part is the fractional part and the date part the integer part, so if you date is genuinely just a date (no time part at all) and your time is genuinely just a time (no date part at all) you can simply combine them by adding them together.

For example:

```
SELECT CAST(40597 AS DATETIME), CAST(0.5 AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(40597 AS DATETIME) + CAST(0.5 AS DATETIME)
```

The top SELECT shows what values represent today and 12 noon, and the second line adds them to make a single value representing today at 12 noon.

Comment: That is the short answer is select @d + @t.